# capture the history a Salesperson

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have a requirement where I have to capture the history of a SalesCompany table.

The situation And solution so far:
1) I have table SalesCompany and Employee
2) When the employee contact any company and thinks they can do business with us he/she add this company in our regular database table SalesCompany.
3) I added a column in salesCompany table "Status" which got two values "Open" and "Assigned" 
4) if Employee left from the company I have added the trigger which will update the salesCompany Status column with "Open" related to this guy.
But I have to maintain the history of salesCompany Table,
who brought this company and who is current salesperson and the report should display in the form who brought this company firstly and who is hold it 2nd and 3rd and 4th....nth and who is currently holding it.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a table CompanySalesAssignment with a company ID, an employee ID, and a date. Make the employee ID nullable to indicate "unassigned".  Add a function to return the most recent (i.e. the current) assignment for a given company (which may be to no one if that assignment was added because assigned employee left).